# Issue Filtering Knockout.js observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a knockout.js app that has an observable array.  I've added a filter to the observable array.  The filtering is working properly.  The issue is I'm calling another function as I'm filtering data.  Here is my function:

```
self.filterResults = function(){
         var value = self.searchInput().toLowerCase();
         if(value != ''){
             clearMarkers();
             self.burgerList(self.burgerList().filter(function(data){
                 addmarker(data.lat(), data.long(), data.id(), data.name(), data.comments());
                 return data.name().toLowerCase().startsWith(value); 
             }));
         }else{
           showMarkers();
           self.burgerList(self.burgerListClone());
         }
     };
```

There seems to be a lag as I'm calling the addmarker while I'm doing the filtering.

I've pasted all the code into a jsfiddle to show an example of what I'm doing:
https://jsfiddle.net/maL3zqgq/5/

Answer (score 1):

Because you're adding the markers before filtering, you'll see the results of the previous filter. You need to add the markers after filtering:

```
         self.burgerList(self.burgerList().filter(function(data){
             return data.name().toLowerCase().startsWith(value); 
         }));
         clearMarkers();
         self.burgerList().forEach(function(data){
             addmarker(data.lat(), data.long(), data.id(), data.name(), data.comments());
         });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbest/maL3zqgq/6/

Comment: If I answered your question, can you accept my answer? Thanks.